# How to close Intel Edison default GPIO in u-boot?

Tags: gpio, u-boot, intel-edison

When the Intel Edison into the u-boot ,it will make Gpio13 output to high and make Gpio12 blink twice.
I think this is caused by u-boot ,and I want to close this one, but I don't know how to do.

I look for relate instructions in edison.dts, but not found anything.

So does anyone have any idea? Thank

Comment: U-Boot doesn't touch those pins at all. I believe it's a firmware. And unfortunately nobody will fix it, if it's the case. For U-Boot there is a very simple pin control stub driver to change I2C bus mode: https://gitlab.denx.de/u-boot/u-boot/-/blob/master/arch/x86/cpu/tangier/pinmux.c

Comment: Thank your replied. I will test this simple pin control stub driver. But can I change these pins form firmware? I want to remove from the original source.

Comment: Hi @0andriy ,I have a question what is merrifield family?And I need to know  memory mapping of the gpio's and pad-offset and mode-func . If I want to use this simple pin control stub driver to change GPIO, first I need to increase the GPIO of configuration pinctrl-tangier in edison.dts ,right? And so I need to know pad-offset and mode-func and default-state(or value) and direction on desired GPIO pin ,right? Can you help finding the doc? Thank you.

Comment: There is no public doc available. Use the official code bomb which was given for Intel Edison (or Intel Merrifield based phone/tablet users by corresponding OEMs) and/or GPIO and pin control drivers in Linux kernel (*drivers/pinctrl/intel/pinctrl-merrified.c*, *drivers/gpio/gpio-merrifield.c*).